# Time Complexity of reading from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I would like to know, which code in thory takes longer:

1.

```
$query = "SELECT Something1, Something2 FROM base WHERE SomeCondition";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
//We do something with $row[0] and row[1]
}
```

2.

```
$query = "SELECT Something1 FROM base WHERE SomeCondition";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
//We do something with $row[0]
}
$query = "SELECT Something2 FROM base WHERE SomeCondition";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
//We do something with $row[0]
}
```

Now 1. should be faster, because while statment executes in O(n) time, while the other in O(2*n), but in the first one it has to query for two columns at once, where in 2. it has to to query for one column, but twice. Now I wonder how performance wise is the mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array on one column at once, or two columns at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option (single query) will run ~2 times faster in given example.

You are probably thinking that since database bottle-neck is typically I/O that the speed should be the same (reading x data from disk or 2 x reading x/2 data), but due to the fact how records are written to the filesystem and the fact that filesystem can only read discrete blocks it follows that it is not any faster to read only one column compared to reading many columns (the difference might, depending on the RDBMS, show only when you have tables with many columns or if the disk I/O is not bottleneck, but for example you access the database through very slow WAN).

Other benefits of running one query are (though minor compared to the above):

- query planner needs to analyze each query and determine how it will execute it
- there is overhead in sending each query to the server

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you will want to use the database engine over PHP for anything both can do, because the former is usually optimized for such things. MySQL is faster at searching and retrieving data than PHP is, and that's why we use it in the first place.

Also, while minimal, the overhead of network connections and socket would render the first solution faster anyway.

Comment: It's the granularity of the I/O operations on the file system that explains it much more then overhead of network connections (and or query planing, etc..). See details in my A